# Material React Table component typing issue

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, material-react-table

I'm using MRT in my react project. I've created a component that returns MRT and I'm reusing this component across the application to avoid repeating the same props everywhere. I'm running through an issue in typing the **columns** props in the component.

Here's my component

```
import React from "react";
import {
  MaterialReactTable,
  type MRT_Row,
  type MaterialReactTableProps,
  MRT_ColumnDef,
  MRT_Column,
} from "material-react-table";
import { MRT_Localization_AR } from "../../locales/ar";

export interface Props<TData extends Record<string, any>> {
  columns: Array<MRT_ColumnDef<TData>>;
  data: MaterialReactTableProps["data"];
  onPaginationChange?: MaterialReactTableProps["onPaginationChange"];
  onColumnFiltersChange?: MaterialReactTableProps["onColumnFiltersChange"];
  onGlobalFilterChange?: MaterialReactTableProps["onGlobalFilterChange"];
  onSortingChange?: MaterialReactTableProps["onSortingChange"];
  initialState?: MaterialReactTableProps["initialState"];
  state?: MaterialReactTableProps["state"];
  renderRowActionMenuItems?: MaterialReactTableProps["renderRowActionMenuItems"];
  renderTopToolbarCustomActions?: MaterialReactTableProps["renderTopToolbarCustomActions"];
  muiTableBodyRowProps: MaterialReactTableProps["muiTableBodyRowProps"];
  isError?: boolean;
  enableGlobalFilter?: boolean;
  enableRowSelection?: boolean;
  manualFiltering?: boolean;
  manualPagination?: boolean;
  manualSorting?: boolean;
  enableEditing?: MaterialReactTableProps["enableEditing"]
  editingMode?: MaterialReactTableProps["editingMode"]
  onEditingRowSave?: MaterialReactTableProps["onEditingRowSave"]
  enableRowActions?: boolean;
}

export const BaseTable: React.FC<Props> = ({ isError, ...props }) => {
  return (
    <MaterialReactTable
      localization={MRT_Localization_AR}
      enableRowActions
      enableColumnOrdering
      enableGrouping
      enablePinning
      {...props}
    />
  );
};
```

Here's an example of columns prop from one page of my application:

```
  const EColumns = useMemo<MRT_ColumnDef<EVariablesType>[]>(
    () => [
    ],
    []
  );
```

And here's the issue I'm getting: `Generic type 'Props' requires 1 type argument(s).ts(2314)

Please note that **EVariablesType** changes in the other places I'm using the component in.

Is there a solution or way around this issue or should I use MRT directly in every place in the app?

I tried using MRT directly in every place in the app, but this resulted in a lot of duplicated and redundant code

Comment: please add your code, the explanation is not enough. A better way to understand is an example

Comment: @Asking the code exists in the description